Verilog Daisy-Chained Ripple Counter in actual FPGA
I am writing cores for old arcade games in Verilog. Firstly I create the simulation, based off the arcade schematics and then proceed to FPGA. I have a problem of metastability when reproducing the daisy-chained ripple counters, which are used to create video sync signals and video ram bus counting methods.
There are two modules used:
module ls74
(
    input  pre_n,
    input  clr_n,
    input  clk,
    input  d,
    output reg q,
    output q_n
);

always @(posedge clk or negedge pre_n or negedge clr_n) begin
    if(!pre_n)
        q <= 1;
    else if(!clr_n)
        q <= 0;
    else
        q <= d;
end
assign q_n = ~q;

endmodule

and
module ls161 //asynchronous reset/clear
(
    input        clr_n,
    input        clk,
    input  [3:0] din,
    input        enp, ent,
    input        load_n,
    output [3:0] q,
    output       rco
);

  reg [3:0] data = 4'b0;

always @(posedge clk or negedge clr_n) begin
    if(!clr_n)
        data <= 4'd0;
    else
        if(!load_n)
            data <= din;
        else if(enp && ent)
            data <= data + 4'd1;
end

assign q = data;
assign rco = data[0] & data[1] & data[2] & data[3] & ent;

endmodule

this is connected as below:
module champb_top;

reg PUR=1'b1;
reg clk = 1'b0;
reg nRESET = 1'b1;

always #1 clk <= ~clk;

initial
  begin
  $dumpfile("dump.vcd");
  $dumpvars(2);
  #10 nRESET=1'b0;
    #1 PUR=1'b0;
    #49 PUR=1'b1;
  #49 nRESET = 1'b1;
  #500000 $finish;  
  end

reg [1:0] cnt1 = 2'b00;
always @(posedge clk)
    if (!PUR)
        cnt1 <= 2'b00;
    else if (!nRESET)
        cnt1 <= 2'b00;
  else if (cnt1 == 2'b10)
    cnt1 <= 2'b00;
    else
        cnt1 <= cnt1 + 2'd1;
wire M6Hz = ~cnt1[1] == 1'b1;
wire nM6Hz = cnt1[0] == 1'b1;

 wire H1;
 wire IC9L_1_nQ;
 
  ls74 ic9L_1(
    .pre_n(PUR),
    .clr_n(PUR),
    .clk(nM6Hz),
    .d(IC9L_1_nQ),
    .q(H1),
    .q_n(IC9L_1_nQ)
  );


wire phi = ~H1;
wire H2,H4,H8,H16;
wire IC8N_rco;
 
  ls161 ic8N(
    .clr_n(PUR),
    .clk(nM6Hz),//
    .din(4'b0),
    .enp(H1), 
    .ent(H1),
    .load_n(PUR),
    .q({H16,H8,H4,H2}),
    .rco(IC8N_rco)
  );

wire H32,H64,H128,H256;
wire IC8P_rco;

  ls161 ic8P(
    .clr_n(PUR),
    .clk(nM6Hz),//
    .din(4'b0100),
    .enp(IC8N_rco), 
    .ent(IC8N_rco),
    .load_n(~IC8P_rco),
    .q({H256,H128,H64,H32}),
    .rco(IC8P_rco)
  );
 
//end of H counters
//Vertical counters

wire IC8L_2_D = ~(~H64 & H32);
wire IC8L_2_Q,IC8L_2_nQ;
wire IC7P_rco;

  ls74 ic8L_2(
    .pre_n(~H256),
    .clr_n(PUR),
    .clk(H16),
    .d(IC8L_2_D),
    .q(IC8L_2_Q),
    .q_n(IC8L_2_nQ)
  );

 wire V1;
 wire IC9L_2_nQ;
 
  ls74 ic9L_2(
    .pre_n(PUR),
    .clr_n(PUR),
    .clk(IC8L_2_nQ),
    .d(IC9L_2_nQ),
    .q(V1),
    .q_n(IC9L_2_nQ)
  );

wire V2,V4,V8,V16;
wire IC7N_rco;
 
  ls161 ic7N(
    .clr_n(PUR),
    .clk(IC8L_2_nQ),
    .din(4'b1100),
    .enp(V1), 
    .ent(V1),
    .load_n(~IC7P_rco),
    .q({V16,V8,V4,V2}),
    .rco(IC7N_rco)
  );

wire V32,V64,V128,V256;

  ls161 ic7P(
    .clr_n(PUR),
    .clk(IC8L_2_nQ),
    .din(4'b0111),
    .enp(IC7N_rco), 
    .ent(IC7N_rco),
    .load_n(~IC7P_rco),
    .q({V256,V128,V64,V32}),
    .rco(IC7P_rco)
  );

//end of V counters
//video syncs & blanks

wire IC8L_1_D = ~(V32 & V64 & V128);
wire VBLANK,nVBLANK;
wire nCOMPSYNC = (V256 & IC8L_2_Q);

  ls74 ic8L_1(
    .pre_n(PUR),
    .clr_n(PUR),
    .clk(V16),
    .d(IC8L_1_D),
    .q(nVBLANK),
    .q_n(VBLANK)
  );

wire [11:0] vidcnt_in = {1'b0,1'b0,V128,V64,V32,V16,V8,H128,H64,H32,H16,H8};

endmodule 

clk for above is 18MHz in the FPGA, derived from a PLL from the 50MHz system clock. The pixel clock is 6MHz derived from the 18MHz 'clk'.
When using an FPGA I think the counters are assumed to be clocks, but they have different domains and therefore maybe that is why there can be metastability.
My question is whether there is a better way to do this?
The arcade cores that exist split these items separately and use counters from a single variable. However to do that it gets very complicated, since the counters have some initial pre-load that is not zero and it gives characteristic output.
Any help appreciated.

You can't combine signals from multiple clock domains in an FPGA, which it sounds like you already know.  What rates are the clocks that you are using?  If they are slow (as in old video games) you might be able to use a modern medium clock rate (say 100 MHz) and derive strobes from that which are very close to the rates you started with.  Then maybe a CDC fifo could be used to get back to exactly the original rates from 100MHz if needed.  Please add the clock rates to the post rather than replying in the comments.

Clock speeds added as requested.
